# How do I make a menu scroll with the page only within a section?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a page where there is a side menu that scrolls only within a certain section of the page. I'm using Bootstrap where the row has two columns, the left containing the menu I want to scroll, and the right containing the content of the page. There are other rows above and below the one in question. When the user scrolls (or uses the menu) I want the menu to scroll with them, but only within the row it is in (this way it stays only with the content it links to). I've tried using position: fixed, but that lets the menu move outside the parent row. I've also tried position: sticky, but that didn't seem to do anything at all actually. Here is the code I have so far. Thanks in advance for the tips.

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center my-4 service-content">
    <!-- Side Menu -->
    <div class="col-md-4 d-none d-md-flex justify-content-center cosmetic-menu-parent">
      <div id="cosmeticMenu" class="list-group">
        <a
          class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
          href="#list-item-1"
          >BOTOX®</a
        >
        <a
          class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
          href="#list-item-2"
          >Acne</a
        >
        <a
          class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
          href="#list-item-3"
          >Fillers</a
        >
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Section Content -->
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
      <div
        data-spy="scroll"
        data-target="#cosmeticMenu"
        data-offset="0"
        class="scrollspy-example"
      >
        <h4 id="list-item-1" class="mb-4">BOTOX®</h4>
        <h5>What is BOTOX®?</h5>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
          enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
          nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
        <h4 id="list-item-2">Acne</h4>
        <p>...</p>
        <h4 id="list-item-3">Fillers</h4>
        <p>...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `position:sticky` with z-index property. And also use the fixed menu within empty parent div `sampleDiv`. I hope this solution will be helpful for you.

```css
.stickyMenu {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1019;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center my-4 service-content">
    <!-- Side Menu -->
    <div class="col-md-4 d-none d-md-flex justify-content-center cosmetic-menu-parent">
      <div class="sampleDiv">
        <div class="stickyMenu">
          <div id="cosmeticMenu" class="list-group">
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#list-item-1">BOTOX®</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#list-item-2">Acne</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#list-item-3">Fillers</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Section Content -->
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
      <div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#cosmeticMenu" data-offset="0" class="scrollspy-example">
        <h4 id="list-item-1" class="mb-4">BOTOX®</h4>
        <h5>What is BOTOX®?</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <h4 id="list-item-2">Acne</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
        <h4 id="list-item-3">Fillers</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="height: 900px;">&nbsp;</div><!-- Remove this height in your code -->
```